# Coger valor input radio o input checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una consulta a base de datos que me saca varios radios e checkbox y quiero coger el valor y guardarlo en un array en jquery al pinchar un boton.¿se podría hacer sin coger el name?
tengo una preguna con varias respuestas y cada pregunta esta en un tabla y al sacar todas preguntas hay un input button

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un formulario de ejemplo? Poder, se puede, pero depende de cómo lo tengas montado o en qué momento quieras acceder a esos datos. Te voy poniendo un ejemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas jQuery para este trabajo. Puedes hacer uso de [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) para realizar tu trabajo y luego [`FormData.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) para iterar por todos los campos del formulario:

```js
function comprobar(obj) {
  var formulario = new FormData(obj);
  document.getElementById('salida').innerText = '';
  /* Recorremos todos los valores (entries) */
  for(var dupla of formulario.entries()) {
    document.getElementById('salida').innerText += dupla[0]+ ': '+ dupla[1] + "\n";
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<pre id="salida"></pre>
<form onsubmit="return comprobar(this)">
  <input type="hidden" name="oculto" value="valor oculto" /><br />
  <input type="text" name="texto" value="valor de texto" /><br />
  <input type="password" name="contraseña" value="valor de contraseña" /><br />
  <textarea name="areadetexto">Contenido del área de texto</textarea><br />
  <select name="colores" multiple>
    <option value="rojo" selected>Color Rojo</option>
    <option value="azul">Color Azul</option>
    <option value="negro" selected>Color Negro</option>
  </select><br />
  <input type="radio" name="modelo" value="nuevo" checked> Coche nuevo<br />
  <input type="radio" name="modelo" value="viejo"> Coche viejo<br />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```